# How would I improve the language and structure of this farewell email?

Tags: email, career, letter

I will shortly be moving to another a role within the same organisation and was wondering if you could advise on how I could improve the language and structure of this farewell email. It seems a bit drawn out at the moment and I'd like it to retain the sincerity yet exude a sharpness that will create future opportunities by extending bridges.

> Dear all,
>
> As many of you know, today is my last day with compliance. Through
>   this farewell email, I wanted to thank you for your continued support
>   and guidance. During the last six months, I have had the privilege to
>   work with genuinely talented people like yourself, who have helped me
>   grow both personally and professionally.
>
> With my first rotation
>   drawing to a close, I look back with pleasure on everything that we
>   have accomplished together. I only hope that I find in my new role a
>   fraction of the encouragement, gratitude and opportunities that I have
>   found here.
>
> I have really enjoyed my time and will miss working with
>   you all. I owe you an enormous debt of gratitude and I wish each one
>   of you, the very best in all your future endeavours, both professional
>   and personal. Thanks again for everything.
>
> Regards

Comment: I just had a thought: is this on topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit gushing but I guess that's your style. It looks good -- you don't really need help with writing. Except

- Capitalize "Compliance" if it's a department name.
- Replace "talented people like yourself," with "talented people," -- they know you're addressing them.
- Replace "I only hope that I find in my new role a fraction of the encouragement" with "I hope that I find in my new role the encouragement" -- toning it down a notch.

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by gushing?

Comment: gushing (adjective)
▸expressing admiration or pleasure with so much enthusiasm that people think you are not sincere <http://www.onelook.com/?w=gushing&ls=a>

Comment: Ok thanks - any advice on how I could make it more sincere?

Comment: I added 3rd item. It doesn't make it more sincere, just _sound_ less "over-the-top".

Comment: Thanks again - this is my first farewell email, a bit difficult to pen

Comment: And if the answer works for you, feel free to "accept" it (click check mark) :-)

Comment: I don't know what prevents you from saying goodbye in person, but I would feel strange to receive an email like this. If a coworker does not say goodbye to me personally, then we did not have the relationship to warrant a goodbye in writing. Here, we have the nice custom to bring a cake or food and drink on your (first and) last day and throw some small kind of party. That way even those that you were not close to feel included, and it gives you an opportunity to hold a gushing speech without anyone finding it so. In a few years, they will remember you being nice, but not what you said.

Comment: That's a good point, what. Maybe the OP should ask over at http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ with a reworded introduction: "would this work as a farewell..."